# why navigate up not supporting to view pager (child fragments)

Tags: android

I am trying to getting location details from other fragment by using navigateup to view pager fragments(child fragments) but its not redirecting to child fragment its redirecting to parent fragment.is it possible to navigating directly to child fragment?